# I want to pass the variables referencing cell addresses into a sum formula in the excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet consisting of main tasks and sub tasks, I need the sub-tasks to sum up to the main task. The issue is that the sub-tasks may be 1 or more sub task each time all in the same column. This must happen in a VBA code and insert the beginning sub-task line and ending sub task line in each main task. so that if the spreadsheet is edited the main task value will reflect the changes.

I have tried creating ranges to hold the beginning and ending sub tasks addresses and the main task address. but when i try to put it into a formula to insert into the spreadsheet it show the variable names of what should be the cell addresses.

```
Sub DynamoRange()
    Dim range1 As Range
    Dim range2 As Range
    Dim range3 As Range
    Dim range4 As Range
    Dim range5 As Range
    Dim badd
    Dim eadd

    Dim placeholder
    Dim counter3

    Set range1 = Range("A1")
    Set range2 = Range("E1")

    'Find 1st Main Task'
NextLine1:

    'Handles beginning section of spreadsheet blanks
    If IsNumeric(range2.Offset(counter3, 0)) = True And range1.Offset(counter3, 0) <> "Yes" Then
        counter3 = counter3 + 1
        GoTo NextLine1
    Else
        If IsNumeric(range2.Offset(counter3, 0)) = False And range1.Offset(counter3, 0) <> "Yes" Then
            counter3 = counter3 + 1
            GoTo NextLine1 
        Else
            'Beginning of a new section Set Start and Sum reference
            If IsNumeric(range2.Offset(counter3, 0)) = True And range1.Offset(counter3, 0) = "Yes" And range1.Offset(counter3 - 1, 0) <> "Yes" Then        
                Set range3 = range2.Offset(counter3 - 1, 0)
                Set range4 = range3.Offset(1, 0)

                counter3 = counter3 + 1
                GoTo NextLine1
            Else
                'Set the ending sum point for the task order and apply Ranges - 3-5 into a formula before moving to next section
                If IsNumeric(range2.Offset(counter3, 0)) = True And range1.Offset(counter3, 0) = "Yes" And range1.Offset(counter3 + 1, 0) <> "Yes" Then
                    Set range5 = range2.Offset(counter3, 0)

                    badd = range3.Address(, , xlR1C1)
                    eadd = range4.Address(, , xlR1C1)

                    range3.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(range3.Address(,,xlR1C1):
```

'END OF CODE - below are attempts to get the addresses to pass into the SUM Formula

```
 'range3.FormulaR1C1 = 
"=SUM(Address(badd,badd,,0,,):Address(eadd,eadd,,0,))"


'range3.Formula = "=SUM(Address(badd,badd,,0,,):Address(eadd,eadd,,0,))"

'CURRENT EXCEL RESULT =SUM(range3.Address(,,xlR1C1): range4.Address(,,xlR1C1))
```

Comment: Without any indenting it's difficult to follow your code

Comment: Sorry - self taught let me see if i can clean it up

Comment: i was going to edit your `code` in the question but... your code isn't complete... there is no `end sub`

Comment: Correct this is the beginning, I got stuck trying to pass the address into a formula. other than that its just going to loop and find the next instance. until it reached the end of the spreadsheet...in the current case row 330 end if counter = 330 goto exit exit: end sub. Sorry i'm new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn how to concatenate strings correctly with `&`:

```
Dim badd As String
Dim eadd As String

badd = range3.Address(, , xlR1C1)
eadd = range4.Address(, , xlR1C1)

range3.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & badd & ":" & eadd & ")"
```

Also I highly recommend to avoid using `Goto` this is a very bad practice.

You should also check if you want to use a `ElseIf` statement instead of `Else` … `If` (since your code is not complete it's hard to suggest something concrete here).

Comment: Yes that was it, I did look at the concatenate but wasn't sure how it was being used when regular formulas worked without it. Goto has been my default but i have been looking at the Do and Do While. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: @SrednasX If *"Goto has been my default"* then I highly recommend to change your habits as soon as possible. You cannot write good code using `Goto` (unless you use it for error handling).